# Is it possible to drive from Bergen to Folgefonna?

Tags: driving, norway, bergen

I'm trying to plan a day trip from Bergen to Hardangerfjorden. I found in another site someone saying

> Other options, like mentioned before, is to travel to Hardangerfjorden on day excursion from Bergen (can be done by public bus or by excursion vessels). If you go to Norheimsund you can be able to walk behind a famous waterfall (Steindalsfossen), see the big waterfall Vøringsfossen or the glacier Folgefonna - all very spectacular

My question is about doing this in a car if I would like to drive myself. Is it possible. Or is this somehow only accessible to public transportation.

Trying to get directions from Google to drive from Bergen to these location doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule: If you can get there by bus, you can get there by car. There are of course cases where there are restrictions regarding private cars, but that's not the case for the places you're asking about.

Steinsdalsfossen og Vøringsfossen are both on FV-7. Have a look at [route plan](https://goo.gl/maps/zK3oVqCSJSB2) in Google Maps to see how to get there.

Folgefonna is large, and there are many different places you can visit. If you want to start at the [summer ski center](http://visitfonna.no/en/), it will take you [2 h 45 min](https://goo.gl/maps/kiUa9gySx8C2).